# Invoking a script with sudo ignores the shebang

Tags: bash, shell, sudo, dash, shebang

Invoking a script using sudo ignores the shebang and runs the script in a different shell. To test, I created a script (test.sh) containing:

```
#/bin/bash
echo "BASH is: $BASH"
echo "actual shell is: `readlink /proc/$$/exe`"
```

First, I invoke the script **without sudo**:

```
$ ./test.sh
BASH is: /bin/bash
actual shell is: /bin/bash
```

Then, I invoke the script **with sudo**:

```
$ sudo ./test.sh
BASH is:
actual shell is: /bin/dash
```

I would not have expected this. Is this normal behavior?

Note: I'm using Ubuntu (14.04), where the default shell **/bin/sh** is a symlink to **dash**.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your shebang isn't a shebang. It's just a she, missing the bang:

```
#!/bin/bash
```

Corrected example:

```
$ ./test.sh
BASH is: /bin/bash
actual shell is: /bin/bash
$ sudo ./test.sh
BASH is: /bin/bash
actual shell is: /bin/bash
$ cat ./test.sh 
#!/bin/bash
echo "BASH is: $BASH"
echo "actual shell is: `readlink /proc/$$/exe`"
```

Answer (score 3):

Your example omits the `!` character, e.g., you should have `#!/bin/bash`

Without a valid hashbang line, you will get the *default shell*, which is **dash**.